# Failed transaction

Tags: failed-transaction

Hi I’m trying to withdraw funds from a contract but keep getting a failed transaction. This is the message. Can anyone throw some light on it?

```
Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "type": "0x2", "from": "0xd8890cbf7d6bebdb419725a4c33ed4ca1f573d1a", "to": "0x51bd63f240fb13870550423d208452ca87c44444", "status": false, "cumulativeGasUsed": 6571006, "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "transactionHash": "0xf3db8b3109f9a497df7447c11e4f0b21888f4729a6ac8b3811ada313164507a4", "contractAddress": null, "gasUsed": 580764, "blockHash": "0x1968a9e69049c484ee2d92b15ad2355149890c1eaf2d76978537cc26180749b5", "blockNumber": 32992606, "transactionIndex": 51, "effectiveGasPrice": 3000000000, "events": {} }
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

Increasing GasLimit may solve your problem.You can try setting it to 800,000.

Comment: Just tried it with 1,000,000 and still the same. It used 74.46% of the max gas. This time the error reads Fail with error 'SafeMath: division by zero' here’s the txid 0xe97767691a46fa0c63a5db2081082a4849f099fe7233b561748b7743ba2920c8